# Can we substract two date and compare for a field in WorkFlow on CRM Dynamics

Tags: dynamics-crm-4

I want to subtract two date field and if the value is more than 15 days then only I should update the some of the fields in CRM records. Can we implement this using Workflow.

```
If (Submission date - Created on) >= 15
```

Update the CRM entity

I want to implement this using Workflow under CRM dynamics 4.0, is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is you doing a custom activity to check that. Check this article:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328515.aspx

I don't know what you trying to do but i can use Javascript to do that:

```
var firstDate = crmForm.all.somedate1.DataValue;
var secondDate = crmForm.all.somedate2.DataValue;
if((firstDate.getDate() - secondDate.getDate()) >= 15)
      //Do Something
```

I don't test the code use like as a guide.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new attribute (xxx_daysdifference) to the entity to store the date difference, and then using javascript on the 'onsave' event calculate the date different and populate the attribute.

Then you can use a workflow to act on that attribute.